# How to extend user schema using WSO2 charon scim library

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am creating a SCIM server using Charon library. How to extend user schema using WSO2 charon scim library?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to extend the schema using charon library.

**Option 1:**

Define the attribute definitions in a file and build the schema using the file.
When writing that file, the final config in the configuration file should be the definition of the extension.

*Method to use in charon:* https://github.com/wso2/charon/blob/27562f69ce5b23b4e85015daf5aa11c651a91a8c/modules/charon-core/src/main/java/org/wso2/charon3/core/config/SCIMUserSchemaExtensionBuilder.java#L63

sample java code to build schema using this method:

```
  String schemaFilePath = "<absolute path to the schema defined file>";
  SCIMUserSchemaExtensionBuilder.getInstance().buildUserSchemaExtension(schemaFilePath);
  AttributeSchema extensionSchema = SCIMUserSchemaExtensionBuilder.getInstance().getExtensionSchema();
  // print the attribute URIs in the built schema
  extensionSchema.getSubAttributeSchemas().stream().forEach(e->System.out.print(e.getURI() + "\n"));
```

*refer:* https://github.com/AnuradhaSK/schema-extension/blob/cea1fa636bea2bb1e599ac9c71c6c45eaa339199/src/main/java/ScimSchemas.java#L29-L35

*Format of the file:* https://github.com/AnuradhaSK/schema-extension/blob/main/src/main/resources/custom-schema

**Option 2:**

Use SCIMCustomSchemaExtensionBuilder in charon.

- You have to define the extended schema URI first.
- Then create
  SCIMCustomAttribute objects for each attribute you need to add to the extended schema. You have to define the default set of attribute properties mentioned in the scim schema for an attribute
- Finally create another SCIMCustomAttribute to represent the extended schema
- Put all objects to a List and call `buildUserCustomSchemaExtension` method in SCIMCustomSchemaExtensionBuilder

Method to use in charon:
https://github.com/wso2/charon/blob/27562f69ce5b23b4e85015daf5aa11c651a91a8c/modules/charon-core/src/main/java/org/wso2/charon3/core/config/SCIMCustomSchemaExtensionBuilder.java#L71

*sample java code:*

```
            SCIMCustomSchemaExtensionBuilder.getInstance().setURI("urn:scim:custom:extended:schemas");
            LOG.info("====Attributes of extended schema using custom attributes===");
            // Sub attribute of the schema.
            Map<String, String> subAttributeProperties = new HashMap<>();
            subAttributeProperties.put("attributeURI","urn:scim:custom:extended:schemas:vehicleNo");
            subAttributeProperties.put("attributeName","vehicleNo");
            subAttributeProperties.put("dataType","string");
            subAttributeProperties.put("multiValued","false");
            subAttributeProperties.put("description","User's vehicle number");
            subAttributeProperties.put("required","false");
            subAttributeProperties.put("caseExact","false");
            subAttributeProperties.put("mutability","readWrite");
            subAttributeProperties.put("returned","default");
            subAttributeProperties.put("uniqueness","none");
            subAttributeProperties.put("canonicalValues","[]");
            SCIMCustomAttribute scimCustomAttribute = new SCIMCustomAttribute();
            scimCustomAttribute.setProperties(subAttributeProperties);

            // Schema object.
            Map<String, String> schemaObjectProperties = new HashMap<>();
            schemaObjectProperties.put("attributeURI","urn:scim:custom:extended:schemas");
            schemaObjectProperties.put("attributeName","urn:scim:custom:extended:schemas");
            schemaObjectProperties.put("dataType","complex");
            schemaObjectProperties.put("multiValued","false");
            schemaObjectProperties.put("description","Extended custom schema");
            schemaObjectProperties.put("required","false");
            schemaObjectProperties.put("caseExact","false");
            schemaObjectProperties.put("mutability","readWrite");
            schemaObjectProperties.put("returned","default");
            schemaObjectProperties.put("uniqueness","none");
            schemaObjectProperties.put("subAttributes","vehicleNo");
            schemaObjectProperties.put("canonicalValues","[]");
            SCIMCustomAttribute schemaAttribute = new SCIMCustomAttribute();
            schemaAttribute.setProperties(schemaObjectProperties);

            List<SCIMCustomAttribute> attributeList = new ArrayList<>();
            attributeList.add(scimCustomAttribute);
            attributeList.add(schemaAttribute);
            AttributeSchema customExtendedSchema = SCIMCustomSchemaExtensionBuilder.getInstance().buildUserCustomSchemaExtension(attributeList);
            customExtendedSchema.getSubAttributeSchemas().stream().forEach(e->System.out.print(e.getURI() + "\n"));
```

refer: https://github.com/AnuradhaSK/schema-extension/blob/cea1fa636bea2bb1e599ac9c71c6c45eaa339199/src/main/java/ScimSchemas.java#L39-L78